# Mongoose.model vs Connection.model vs Model.model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, odm

I am bit confused with usage of models in [mongoosejs](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html)

Models can be created using mongoose in these ways

**Using Mongoose**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Actor = mongoose.model('Actor', new Schema({ name: String }));
```

**Using Connection**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection(..);
db.model('Venue', new Schema(..));
var Ticket = db.model('Ticket', new Schema(..));
var Venue = db.model('Venue');
```

**Using existing Model instance**

```
var doc = new Tank;
doc.model('User').findById(id, callback);
```

Now what is the difference between model returned by [`Mongoose.model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model) , [`Connection.model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-model) and [`Model.model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-model). and when to use what , 
 what is the recommended way to create/fetch model ?

Answer (score 23):

1. `mongoose.model` ties the defined model to the default connection that was created by calling `mongoose.connect`.
2. `db.model` ties the model to the connection that was created by calling `var db = mongoose.createConnection`.
3. `doc.model` looks up another model by name using the connection that `doc`'s model is tied to.

All three can be sensibly used in the same program; which one to use just depends on the situation.

Answer (score 16):

ok here is what [I found](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose)

> Important! If you opened a separate connection using
>   mongoose.createConnection() but attempt to access the model through
>   mongoose.model('ModelName') it will not work as expected since it is
>   not hooked up to an active db connection. In this case access your
>   model through the connection you created:

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('your connection string');
var MyModel = conn.model('ModelName', schema);
var m = new MyModel;
m.save() // works
```

vs

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('your connection string');
var MyModel = mongoose.model('ModelName', schema);
var m = new MyModel;
m.save() // does not work b/c the default connection object was never connected
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose.connect is for you connect to same database,although your database is balance or replicaSet

db.model is for  multiple connections open to Mongo, each with different read/write settings